# The area A is known. What is the area B of the smallest square.

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, problem-solving, area

[This is the accompanying figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/22avc.png)

[image]

> Given three squares as in the figure, where the largest square has area 1, and the area A is known. What is the area B of the smallest square.

Upon lookin at the answer for this excercise, I found the following reasoning as part of the solution:

> Let the corner of A divide the sides of the big square in two parts x and 1-x. square B have side-length y. For the corner of B to touch the side of A, we must have y/x + y/(1-x) = 1 (the equation for a line)

I do not understand anything about the part with the line-equation, but this seems like a powerful tool i shall have use of knowing. Could someone please explain this for me?

Answer (score 1):

The figure has a lot of **similar** right triangles. From their leg proportions, we conclude
$$  x:(1-x) = (x-y):y=y:(1-x-y)$$

Comment: Thank you, this is helpful. Could you also please show how this leads to y/x + y/(1-x) = 1 and explain why the makers of the question claim this to be the equation of a line? Is it possible to reach this equation without using triangle similarity. I am led to believe it is since those who made the question didnt go through this step before the conclusion that y/(1.x) + y/x = 1